# Manually laying out fields from an inline formset in Django

Tags: django, django-templates

I have created an inline formset for the profile information which is added to the user form:

```
UserSettingsFormSet = inlineformset_factory(
    User,
    Profile,
    form=ProfileForm,
    can_delete=False,
    fields=(
        "title",
        ...
    ),
)


class SettingsView(UpdateView):
    model = User
    template_name = "dskrpt/settings.html"
    form_class = UserForm

    def get_object(self):
        return self.request.user

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(SettingsView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context["formset"] = UserSettingsFormSet(
            instance=self.request.user, prefix="user"
        )
        return context
```

This works and calling `{formset}` in the template file renders the complete form for both `User` and `Profile`.

Yet, I would like to lay out the individual inputs myself. This works for fields belonging to `User`:

```
<input 
  type="text" 
  name="{{form.last_name.html_name}}" 
  id="{{form.last_name.auto_id}}" value="{{form.last_name.value}}">
```

But doing the same for fields of the formset does not work. Here the attribute `formset.form.title.value` appears to be empty. All other attributes, e.g. `formset.form.title.auto_id` exist though.

Why does `{{formset}}` render completely with values but values are missing individually?

Answer (score 1):

#### To answer your questions shortly:

The reason why profile fields are not showing is that they belong to a context data `formset` instead of `form`.

If you check the source code of `UpdateView`, it inherits from a `ModelFormMixin`, which defines methods related to forms, such as `get_form_class`.

#### Why this matter?

Because `get_form_class` grab the attribute `form_class = UserForm` or from your `model` attribute, and pass an **context variable** to your template called `form`. Thus in your template, the `form` variable only refers to `UserForm`, not your `formset`.

#### What is a context variable?

To make it simple that is a variable passed to your template, when your `view` is rendering the page, it will use those variables to *fill in* those `{{}}` slots.

I am sure you also use other generic views such as `ListView`, and probably you have overwritten the `get_context_data` method. That basically does the same thing to define what data should be passed to your template.

#### So how to solve?

**Solution A:**
You need to use `formset` in your template instead of `form`, however this would be quite complicated:

```html
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {{ form_set.management_form }}
    {{ form_set.non_form_errors }}

{% for form in formset.forms %}
    {% for field in form.visible_fields %}
        {# Include the hidden fields in the form #}
        {% if forloop.first %}
          {% for hidden in form.hidden_fields %}
             {{ hidden }}
          {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
        {{ field.errors.as_ul }}
        {{ field }}
    {% endfor %}
    {{ form.non_field_errors }}
{% endfor %}

{# show errors #}
{% for dict in formset.errors %}
    {% for error in dict.values %}
        {{ error }}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
</form>
```

**Solution B:**
Pass correct variable in your view, which will be easier to use:

```py
class SettingsView(UpdateView):
    model = User 
    #...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.POST:
            data["formset"] = UserSettingsFormset(self.request.POST, instance=self.object)
        else:
            data["formset"] = UserSettingsFormset(instance=self.object)
        return data
```

Then in your template you can simply do:

```html
<h1>User Profile</h1>
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <h2>Profile</h2>
    {{ formset.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save">
</form>
```

I think in your formest the form attribute is not necessary `form=ProfileForm,`, by default `inlineformset_factory` will look for a `ModelForm` as `form`, and in this case is your `User` model.

**Solution C:** Is that really necessary to use a `formset`? Formest is usually used to generate multiple forms related to an object, which means should be considered to use in a `many-to-one` relationship.

Usually, for the case of `User` and `Profile`, they are in`OneToOne` relationship, namely, each user only has one profile object. In this case, you can just pass your profile form into your template:

```py
class SettingsView(UpdateView):
    model = User 
    template_name = "dskrpt/settings.html"
    form_class = UserForm
    #...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        data = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        profile = self.request.user.profile
        # your Profile model should have an one-to-one field related with user, and related name should be 'profile'
        # or profile = Profile.objects.get(user=self.request.user)
        data['profile_form'] = ProfileForm(instance=profile)
        return data
```

Then in your template, you can refer to the profile form by `profile_form` only.

As a conclusion, I will suggest using **solution C**.

More detailed example for inline formsets: check [this project](https://github.com/philgyford/django-nested-inline-formsets-example/tree/main/publishing/books)